# Javascript switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I am working on a zodiac calendar that requires a switch 0-11 for the signs. I have written HTML code that drops down for the month and a text input for the year. The sign should use id 'output' and should also show up in text. I am not sure if I am using my switch correctly, of if my math is causing the problem or why it is not sending to output.

HTML CODE:

```
            <div><label for="sign">Sign</label><input type="text" 
            name ="sign" id="sign"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```
    if (year && year.value && (year.length == 4)){
        year = parseInt(years.value);
        month = parseInt(month.value);
        if (month < 2) {
            year = (year - 1);
        }

        year = ((year - 1924) % 12);

    } else { // Show Error:
        document.getElementById('year').value = 
        'Please enter valid values.';
    }

    switch (year){
        case 0 :
            block code;
            break;
            etc..

    } // End Switch


    if (output.textContent != undefined) {
        output.textContent = sign;

    } else {
        output.innerText = sign;
    } 

    return false;

}
```

Comment: can you show how you're deriving `url`?

Comment: FYI, wouldn't it be simpler to replace that `switch` statement with an array? `var signs = ['Rat', 'Ox', ...]; sign = signs[year];`

Comment: I have to use a switch statement. Also I am not deriving any urls in my code. I dont know why this error keeps coming up

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression could be failing to match your lowercased url. When that happens, the result would be `null`.

You should be checking the `match()` result before using it. Something like this:

```
var matches = url.toLowerCase().match(/https?:\/\/(.+?)[?#\/$]/);
if (!matches || matches.length < 2) {
   // Handle error
   ...
} else {
  // Keep going
  var domain = matches[1];
  ...
}
```

Also, verify that your regular expression is actually doing what you intend.

Comment: So Far I caught this code error and corrected it but still nothing : year = parseInt(years.value);

Comment: OK I got it to work, I realized my HTML code also was trying to pull sign instead of output. And I have a javascript code to use paragraph and span so I placed a <p><span> in my html with id='output' instead of the label sign

Comment: I was just about to mention that you had no `output` element. I'm glad you figured that out yourself.

Comment: So i think there is something wrong with my firefox browser because that error is not coming from my code files. It keeps point to this... http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_preloader.jsp?dlsource=linkury&userId=16AF47B9-805A-4B2C-8D0&CTID=Quickshare&ver=14.09.11.07

Answer (score 0):

Because of my javascript code innerText

```
    if (output.textContent != undefined) {
        output.textContent = sign;

    } else {
        output.innerText = sign;
    }
```

I had to delete

```
<div><label for="sign">Sign</label><input type="text" 
        name ="sign" id="sign"></div>
```

and replace it with

```
<p>Sign: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

I could have easily changed the javascript code and document.getElementID('output') = sign.value;

Answer (score -1):

The problem should be caused by domain checking instead of calculate function.

Remove domain checking and try again (see if it works).

Errors:

1) if (year && year.value && (year.**value**.length == 4)){
           year = parseInt(**year**.value);

2) main html didn't declare element "output"

Comment: I did not add any domain checking into my code? or I dont think I did. Only thing in my html code is <script src="js/zodiac.js"></script>

Comment: Can you provide html so I can repeat the issue?

Comment: Thanks Charles, I came to that conclusion as well by deleting the year.value.lenth == 4 part and then putting output in html.

Comment: Use F12 Developer Tools (IE or Chrome), you can easily debug JavaScript.